# Unable to scraping a review page using python,selenium and beautiful soup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a Flipkart review page

```
https://www.flipkart.com/reviews/b9ec5c5c-3814-40ef-8f73-84f253ee09ce
```

I'm using python, beautiful soup & selenium.
Below is code

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:\ESS\Intern-Shubham\chromedriver.exe',options=options)
driver.get('https://www.flipkart.com/reviews/b9ec5c5c-3814-40ef-8f73-84f253ee09ce')
time.sleep(20)
WebDriverWait(driver,
delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_3t4Eas')))
print('Page is ready!')
```

No matter how much delay I'm adding the actual review is not been loaded into the page, below is the snip of review which loads up after some time.
[image]

Any hints suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import By.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

WebDriverWait(driver,
              20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'_3t4Eas')))
print('Page is ready!')
```

your locator is wrong , now you can remove time.sleep()

### you should pass a tuple with locator strategy and locator , not element

Comment: it results in a runtime error.
NameError: name 'By' is not defined

Comment: import By  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By